# Is that a good idea to keep CommunicationManager framework in my iOS project

Tags: ios, afnetworking, 32bit-64bit

I have an old iOS app where it is using Communication Manager framework to communicate with my server. Since communication framework library files architectures are 32bit and I can not change the app architecture to 64bit because of these lib files. So I removed the communication manager framework totally and added AFNetworking for this app.

In my other old app, it is also using communication manager framework but that app is not using those 32bit lib files directly. Project is finding these lib files by library search path, but it's not included in the project 'Linked Framework and Libraries' section. Somehow communication framework is using AFNetworking framework, which is also used in this 2nd project. And this project architecture is 64bit.

NOW, is that a good idea to remove the communication manager framework totally from my 2nd project as well and use AFNetworking or just keep it as it is since it is not causing any problem now and app architecture is 64bit. I know from next iOS release Apple is going to support 64bit architecture app only.

Note: I didn't develop any of these apps from scratch.

Comment: so you have a mess with old libs and asking shall you clean that ?

Comment: Yes. I cleared up the first app to make it compatible with 64bit architecture. But for 2nd app since communication framework is not causing any problem and it's already 64bit, is that worthy to spend time to make it clear as well. That' my main question.